# Host purchased domain name in apache2 ubuntu server

Tags: apache2, dns

I have been looking for a solution to this for months with no luck so here goes. I installed the Ubuntu server 13.04 (since upgraded to 13.10) on an old dell e510 and installed apache2. Also I purchased a domain name from GoDaddy. I cannot find/figure out how to host that website from my server. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to AU!

I will try to keep this ASAP (as simple as possible) and explain it in steps:

1. Set a **static IP** on your Ubuntu box. (http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu)
2. Go into your router config and set up **port forwarding** of port 80 to the static IP you set in step 1.
3. Get your **Public IP**. (http://www.whatismyip.com/)
4. Go to your **DNS** and point *.domain.com to your IP from step 3.
5. **Start Apache** on your PC.
6. *(optional)* **Get Webmin** and use it for Apache administration. (http://www.webmin.com/deb.html)

Enjoy!

One Final Note: Ask your web provider for a Static IP! It will keep you from redoing steps 3/4 every `n` hours.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I have already done steps 1 through 3, but am having trouble with 4 - can't figure out how to do that. Would you mind breaking that step down a little further? I don't have to add any .html files to an apache2 dir or anything?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know how GoDaddy's control panel works. Try contacting them over live support. It is *not* necessary to add HTML files to have a working Apache. But for future reference, html/php/etc files go into `/var/www/`